# Show remaining time for user unlock based on current datetime and LastLockoutDate

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to show a counter for when a user account is automatically unlocked.

I would like the counter stored within unlockCounter to display only the number of minutes remaining.

unlockDate is a DateTime stored in a format such as: 11/29/2014 1:06:05 PM.

**EDIT:** This is ultimately what I came up with that works perfectly. Updated in case others are interested.

```
If (CurrentUser IsNot Nothing) Then

    If (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut) Then

        Dim lastLockout As DateTime = CurrentUser.LastLockoutDate
        Dim unlockDate As DateTime = lastLockout.AddMinutes(Membership.PasswordAttemptWindow).AddSeconds(-1)
        Dim unlockCounterMinutes As String = unlockDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Minutes + 1
        Dim unlockCounterSeconds As String = unlockDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Seconds

        If (unlockCounterMinutes > 1) Then
            LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account has been locked - Please try again in " & unlockCounterMinutes & " Minutes"
        ElseIf (unlockCounterSeconds > 1) Then
            LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account has been locked - Please try again in " & unlockCounterSeconds & " Seconds"
        Else
            LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account is now being unlocked - Please login again"
        End If

    End If

End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unlockDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now)` to get a `Timespan` object of the time window left.

Don't let the user in while the `TotalMinutes` or `TotalSeconds` is positive depending on the granularity you want.